# how can i get real time data from the raspberry pi sensor to my android app?

Tags: raspbian, sensor, android, data-transfer

how can I display real-time data from the raspberry pi heat sensor into my android app made with the android studio (not an android app build on a raspberry pi )
every time the sensor measures a temperature a new table row in the android app will be created immediately
, thank you for your help

Comment: Is this a question how to program your android phone?

Comment: Not necessarily as I think there are a number of apps available to do this kind of thing -- you should search the playstore for "Raspberry Pi".  There's also stuff like [nodered](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node-RED) which can provide a device agnostic web interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use MQTT if you are just building the app for yourself.
Here is an app on the Playstore [MQTT Dash](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.routix.mqttdash&hl=en&gl=US) you could try a [public MQTT Broker](https://www.hivemq.com/public-mqtt-broker/) to publish sensor data and subscribe with with app from the app store.

If you are using Python on the Pi you can use [Paho](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/index.php?page=clients/python/index.php) to publish your data.
Once this is working you can add MQTT to your Android app.
Then you have to decide where you want to host the MQTT broker. You could host it on the Pi. Here is a broker you can try [Mosquitto](https://mosquitto.org/).

Comment: thank you timur for this priceless help, the app it's not for me, it's for a company and there are more other functions in the app that am devlopping not just visualizing the sensor data that's why I need just the part of visualising the sensor data in my app , can i do that integrating just a part of the app that you gave me in my app